# PyCharm - Class 'float' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances

Tags: python, classes, pycharm

Estou criando um projeto de análise de uma série temporal, e uma das etapas é realizar o teste Augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) para verificar se existe raiz unitária na série. Em seguida, eu realizo o teste Kwiatkowski-Phillips-Schmidt-Shin (KPSS) para verificar se a série é estacionária. Esses testes são feitos com as funções `adfuller()` e `kpss()`, respectivamente, da biblioteca `statsmodels.tsa.stattools`, que retornam tuplas com um dicionário dentro.

Ao realizar algumas tratativas de formatação do texto contido em cada elemento das tuplas do resultado da função `adfuller()`, o PyCharm está exibindo o aviso abaixo, apesar de executar o código sem nenhum problema.

```
Class 'float' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances
```

Porém, realizando as mesmas trativas em cada elemento das tuplas do resultado da função `kpss()`, nenhum aviso é exibido.

Estou utilizando o PyCharm 2023.2.3 (Community Edition).

O código abaixo reproduz a situação:

```
import random
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller, kpss

random.seed(1)

x = [random.randint(0, 200) for _ in range(0, 900)]

print(x)

result_adf = adfuller(x)
print('\nDickey-Fuller Aumentado')
print(f'Teste Estatístico: {result_adf[0]:.4f}')
print(f'Valor-p: {result_adf[1]:.4f}')
print('Valores Críticos:')
for key, value in result_adf[4].items():
    print(f'\t{key}: {value:.4f}')

result_kpss = kpss(x)
print('\nKwiatkowski-Phillips-Schmidt-Shin')
print(f'Teste Estatístico: {result_kpss[0]:.4f}')
print(f'Valor-p: {result_kpss[1]:.4f}')
print('Valores Críticos:')
for key, value in result_kpss[3].items():
    print(f'\t{key}: {value:.4f}')
```

[Aviso PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nuCK.png)

Executando os comandos abaixo, verifiquei que a classe do primeiro elemento de ambas as tuplas é do tipo `float`:

```
print(result_adf[0].__class__)
<class 'numpy.float64'>
print(result_kpss[0].__class__)
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Há algo que possa ser feito para resolver isso, ou é um bug da IDE?

Comment: Executando o trecho que colocou não ocorre o erro que citou. Tem certeza que é esse o código que está executando?

Comment: Como informei no post, o código é executado normalmente. O **aviso** ocorre na IDE do PyCharm, indicado pela cobrinha amarela embaixo do colchete aberto para buscar os elementos da tupla. Isso pode ser visto claramente na imagem anexada.

Comment: Então pode ignorar, pois só tem relação com a anotação de tipos. Provavelmente essa biblioteca está anotada para retornar um `float` enquanto retorna de fato uma tupla. Não te afetará em nada na execução.

Comment: Como pode ver na implementação dessa função, a *docstring* está mal formatada no campo de retorno (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.html#adfuller), ao invés de anotar corretamente o tipo ele apenas descreve as posições da tupla, fazendo com que o PyCharm interprete o retorno como float apenas.

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro. Esse aviso é muito genérico e dá a impressão que há um problema na forma que eu estou escrevendo meu código ao utilizar uma função de uma biblioteca importada, e não que a função original não especifica o tipo de retorno. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Como comentei, não é um problema no seu código em si, por isso que executa normalmente. É um erro na documentação da função dentro da biblioteca, que descreveu cada campo da tupla de forma que o PyCharm entendeu que o retorno é um `float`.

Se olhar a implementação oficial, verá que está assim:

```
    Returns
    -------
    adf : float
        The test statistic.
    pvalue : float
        MacKinnon's approximate p-value based on MacKinnon (1994, 2010).
    usedlag : int
        The number of lags used.
    nobs : int
        The number of observations used for the ADF regression and calculation
        of the critical values.
    critical values : dict
        Critical values for the test statistic at the 1 %, 5 %, and 10 %
        levels. Based on MacKinnon (2010).
    icbest : float
        The maximized information criterion if autolag is not None.
    resstore : ResultStore, optional
        A dummy class with results attached as attributes.
```

O correto para que o PyCharm entendesse corretamente seria algo como:

```
    Returns
    -------
    (float, float, int, int, dict, float, Optional[ResultStore]): ...
```

Isso deixaria claro para a IDE que o retorn é uma tupla e o tipo de cada posição.